# Track one-time GA event for new user registrations

Tags: zoo-visitor, registration, analytics, signup

On the face of it this seemed like it would be something simple to implement, and a common requirement given how important a metric it is, however after a lot of searching and work around ideas this seems to not be the case (I would like to avoid writing a custom plugin for something so basic).

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to do this simply (no hopping through meta redirects) and keep it strict? Or maybe there is a plugin I have missed? The registration system in question is using zoo_visitor and does not require email authentication.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments from madebyhippo's suggestion, use the free Session add-on (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/session-variables-plugin).

So in your generic site header template (throughout the site), have a conditional similar to:

```
{if logged_out}{exp:session_variables:set name="registration" value="no"}{/if}
```

Then on the page that get's shown on successful registration check this on a conditional and will prevent refresh issues.

```
{if logged_in}
  {if "{exp:session_variables:get name="registration"}" == "no"}
    {exp:session_variables:set name="registration" value="yes"}
    {!-- ADD YOUR GA CODE HERE --}
  {/if}
{/if}
```

Depending on your server session reset it may be possible to re-trigger if they try that "successful registration" page at a later date, but that's going to be on extreme cases.

You could even go to the further extreme of auto-submitting a user account edit form on the success page to save a custom user field and use that instead of the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

An Obvious thought would be to put a Google [click track](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) on the registration button? Since users can only register once, this would do the job wouldn't it?

Why do you need to track registrations via Google? Surely a count of the active members would do the same thing?

Comment: If the registration fails for one reason of another you would have unknowingly tracked an unsuccessful registration - which in essence isn't a registration.

Working with web marketers - they don't want to have to head off to the CMS for 1 metric, and more importantly can't use the data in GA's advanced segments.

Comment: OK - what about successful registrants go to a specific page which is only accessible *after* successful registration. This page can have a log/action on it. Then any reference in the GA for this special page can be considered a successful registration.

Comment: Yep ideal, sort of in place already, but the user can refresh or navigate away and go back tot hat page. I dont see a way of preventing the GA code from firing again. Need a flag in the db really - back to custom plugin *sigh*